# Gradle script for multiple android apps with same code (Cloning an app)

Tags: android, package, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have written an android app and it is deployed on playstore. Now I want to create similar app with different packagename (with some changes in strings and appname). I can copy the code and re-factor it in a while to create another app.

But I want to make it simple to sync further changes. i.e. if there is a change in some activity in app1, I want to accommodate that change in app2 as well.

In what ways can do this easily?

Most basic way that I can think of is writing a script to copy files from one app to other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) which does all you want very conveniently. You can keep the same codebase for an unlimited number and combination of variants of your app and customize each one to your likings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use gradle flavours

For example:

```
productFlavors {
        pro {
            applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.pro"
        }
        free {
            applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.free"
        }
    }
```